# Concurrent access to List within Map

Tags: java, list, concurrency, dictionary

I have written a task listener model as the code below, is that any optimization or bug fixing(if it has) can be done on it, especially the List and the Map accessing?
In this model, creates a Map to hold several List which contains some listeners of users, mostly the size of every List is around 1000.
Two points here:
1. for performance, use HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap?
2. is that a better approach than copying a List and iterate the copied List on multi threads accessing?

```
public class TaskActionManager {

    private static final Map<String, List<TaskActionListener>> listenersMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<TaskActionListener>>();
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors
            .newCachedThreadPool();
    private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static final void addListener(TaskActionListener listener,
            TaskActionType type) {
        // type is an enum
        String key = type.name();

        List<TaskActionListener> list = listenersMap.get(key);
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // Mostly the list is not null
            if (list == null) {
                list = listenersMap.get(key);
                if (list == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList<TaskActionListener>();
                    listenersMap.put(key, list);
                }
            }
            list.add(listener);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static final void removeListener(TaskActionListener listener,
            TaskActionType type) {
        List<TaskActionListener> list = listenersMap.get(type.name());
        if (list == null)
            return;

        lock.lock();
        try {
            list.remove(listener);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static final void fireAction(final TaskAction action) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<TaskActionListener> list = listenersMap.get(action
                        .getType().name());
                if (list == null)
                    return;

                // Make a copy
                List<TaskActionListener> copy = null;
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    copy = new ArrayList<TaskActionListener>(list.size());
                    Collections.copy(list, copy);
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }

                // Iterate the copy
                if (copy != null) {
                    for (TaskActionListener listener : copy) {
                        try {
                            listener.fireAction(action);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)? Also, why are you using a lock here?

Comment: as I know, CopyOnWriteArrayList avoids multi-thread issue by copying  underlying array, I'm not sure this is a good choice, as the operations(add, remove) will be invoked when user login to add listener and logout to remove listern.

Comment: ... is that not what you're doing here manually?

Answer (score 0):

> for performance, use HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap?

Obviously, ConcurrentHashMap is the concurrent version of HashMap. So the answer is, no doubt, ConcurrentHashMap. It is simpler to use, and also more efficient, because you need not lock it, because it is thread-safe.

> is that a better approach than copying a List and iterate the copied List on multi threads accessing?

ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, so you don't need to make a copy in order to be able to iterate. If you don't mind your list to change (by another thread) while iterating over it, which I don't see why you should here, then this is the way to go.

See for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

**Note:**

1. Iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.
2. Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null
   to be used as a key or value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the question 2, you meant  ConcurrentHashMap is proper way than List if I don't mind the list being changed while iterating over it, even if I just want a List structure instead of Map structure?